# How to manage sessions in a small React WebApp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a small React Web Application that takes credentials in a Login Form and based on that redirects user into a PATIENT Dashboard or RECEPTIONIST Dashboard based on the credentials entered.
This is my **App.js** file

```
  class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
              <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
              <Route path="/patient" exact component={PatientUI} />
              <Route path="/receptionist" exact component={ReceptionistUI} />
              <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }
  export default App;
```

PatientUI and ReceptionistUI are the dashboard components respectively. API calls to authenticate the user from Login component to either of these dashboards are implemented using SpringBoot. Since there are only 2 dashboards to show, How can I manage sessions effectively in the React app itself? 
Don't want to make API calls for this.
A workaround is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state that identifies the userType (could have values "patient" or "receptionist") and a method to update that state.

You can then have a generic route for both patients and receptionists and define the component to show based on that state.

```
<Route path="/home" exact component={userType==="patient"?<PatientUI/>:<ReceptionistUI/>} />
```

You can then pass the update method to the login component, to set the right userType.

When a user authenticates in the login component, update userType with the method provided and redirect to the "/home" route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store [jwt](https://jwt.io/) and every request from client can be authenticated on server. From server you can send request to client to render page accordingly (based on credentials and assuming routing happens on client side).